# Windows CMD interprets "y" as immediate command execution

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe

Every input containing the character "y" in the command prompt ends in a new line respectively the command is executed immediately. Because of that it's for example not possible to start a python script.

I don't know since when the problem exists. I use Windows 8.1 Enterprise (x64)

[image: Screenshot cmd.exe]

Comment: Is this happening while booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: No, I’m not booting in Safe Mode.

Comment: Can you reproduce from the Windows "On Screen Keyboard" app?  If not, might be a physical issue with your keyboard, or if you have a fancy keyboard with macros, it may need to be reset or reconfigured.

Comment: This was a request to try to see if it happens in Safe Mode, not a question.

Comment: I wanted to check the behavior with the on screen keyboard and also try it with booting in safe mode. But today the problem doesn't occur. I will try it the next few days and if it occurs again I will give an info. Thanks.